# MailMessage html body length too long

Tags: c#, html, mailmessage

I am trying to send an email with an automatically generated html body. The body is generated from a method that goes to a website and scrapes a bunch of information, and I cannot change how it generates the html.

The html body that gets generated is one huge string. I noticed that when the email sends, it gets cut off so I get some nonsense html at the end of the message. I found a thread online where they suggested that the line length was too long for c#, so I replaced every instance of `<br />` with `<br />\n` as per the thread's suggestion, but this did not help.

In the documentation for `MailMessage` I don't see anything about a maximum body length. What's going on here?

Comment: are you using a StringBuilder to build the html ? also what mechanism are you using to parse out / scrape the data..? can you show the current code that you are using..?

Comment: There's a few things you could check, is it an error within the environment, can the datatype hold that much info and finally does the SMTP server have a maximum message length?

Comment: @DJKRAZE The actual scraping is done by a program that I don't have access to the code for. It just spits out the html for the email in a .html file somewhere and I grab that for my use.

Comment: First of all check the security settings of SMTP server. Also note, that they could be changed, and consider another transport for your data.

Comment: @Smithy The datatype is a `string`. The message has ~37,000 characters. I think the string datatype is capable of holding that many. Would it be the SMTP server's maximum message length then? I assumed `MailMessage` had some hidden max body length.

Comment: What SMTP server are you using? Create a gmail account and see if that works. Alternatively, when I send mail if its a long email I'll often allow the user to view it via a webpage. You could do similar with "View full mail here", it's already HTML so no extra cost really?

Comment: `the SMTP
specifications suggests 76 characters per line, so ideally you'll need to
add carriage returns into your string at these lenghts.` Show the code that you actually are using to build the HTML I highly suggest using a String builder

Comment: As I said before, I don't have access to the code that generates the HTML.